# How to use grid rows and columns with collapsible items?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a grid with several items inside, not all of them are visible: some are collapsed. Is there a simple way in `WPF` to resize the already visible items in the grid when a new item shows up?

Actually my needs are simpler than that: I only have 2 items that must be stacked vertically. Most of the time only one will be visible, but when the second appears I need the first one to resize to a 2/3 of the size of the grid and the second to be placed below filling the remaining place: 1/3.

[image]

I feel like I have to play with the `Grid.Row` properties (and maybe with `Grid.RowSpan`) but I don't know how to achieve the desired behavior without messing it up in the code-behind.

What I've tried is mixing the auto-size with the `LastChildFill` property of `DockPanel` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
<Grid Background="Green">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
          <Setter Property="Height"
                  Value="0.25*" />
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=secondRect,
                                            Path=Visibility}"
                          Value="Collapsed">
              <Setter Property="Height"
                      Value="0" />
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </RowDefinition.Style>
    </RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <!--  Row 1  -->
  <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
              Fill="Blue" />
  <!--  Row 2  -->
  <Rectangle x:Name="secondRect"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Fill="Tomato" />
</Grid>
```

So you're setting a `Style.Trigger` on the second Grid row to check if the element it contains is `Collapsed` and if so set it's Height to "0" and if not it's "0.25*" while `Grid` Row 1 has it's `Height` as * or "all remaining space" which would tie in with this fine.

**Alternate:**

You could do it with `Grid.RowSpan` as well like you mentioned.

```
<Grid Background="Green">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="0.75*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <!--  Row 1  -->
  <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
              Fill="Blue">
    <Rectangle.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan"
                Value="1" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=secondRect,
                                          Path=Visibility}"
                        Value="Collapsed">
            <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan"
                    Value="2" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
  </Rectangle>
  <!--  Row 2  -->
  <Rectangle x:Name="secondRect"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Fill="Tomato"
              Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

Now you got the `Trigger` on the 1'st Row's "element" than the `Grid.RowDefinition` and when you detect the second row's element becomes `Collapsed` you switch the first one's RowSpan to 2 else it stays at 1.

Comment: You opened a new field for me: to modify the styles and properties directly in XAML. Thank you very much.